# Matlab: Can I access workspace variables in function definition?

Tags: matlab

I want to find constants a1, b1 which minimize

[image: \sum_{k=1}^{n} |a_1 x_k + b_1 - y_k|]

So I write following matlab code(`nlp.m`):

```
function NLP
x0 = ones(2, 1);
[a1b1, sum1] = fmincon(@objfun, x0, [], [], [], [], [], [], [])

function sum1 = objfun(a1b1)
sum1 = sum(abs(a1b1(1) * x + a1b1(2) - y));
```

with `x` and `y` n-vector created in workspace

However, when I run `nlp.m` I get the following error:

```
>> nlp
Undefined function or variable 'x'.
...
```

Seems that I can't get access to variables defined in workspace. So how can I
deal with it?

Comment: The best way is to pass `x` into `objfun`, so let `objfun` take `x` as an argument.

Comment: Why not just use a least squares fit, without the need for `fmincon` and all kind of iterative methods?  I expect them to have the same outcome anyhow? I.e. |r| has the same minimum as |r|^2 and therefore r^2, r being the residue.

Comment: @edwinksl Why not just make your comment an answer, with a small example?

Answer (score 1):

You can access variables in the base workspace directly from a script but not a function.
To pass these variables to your objective function see http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html.

So you could change your function to using a script like this:

```
% NLP - script
x0 = ones(2, 1);
f = @(a1b1)objfun(a1b1,x,y);
[a1b1, sum1] = fmincon(@f, x0)
```

And define your objective function in a separate function:

```
function sum1 = objfun(a1b1, x, y)
sum1 = sum(abs(a1b1(1) * x + a1b1(2) - y));
```

An other alternative would be to save the base workspace to a file and load this file in your main function.
In this case you could update your function like this:

```
function nlp
% save workspace variable to file
evalin('base','save(''ws.mat'',''x'',''y'');')
x0 = ones(2, 1);
s=load('ws.mat');
x=s.x;y=s.y;
f = @(a1b1)objfun(a1b1, x, y);
[a1b1, sum1] = fmincon(@f, x0);

function sum1 = objfun(a1b1, x, y)
sum1 = sum(abs(a1b1(1) * x + a1b1(2) - y));
```